# Python co-occurrence table

Tags: python, group-by

So I have a dataset that look like the following;

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["1001","Category1"],["1001","Category1"],["1001","Category2"],["1002","Category1"],["1002","Category3"],["1001","Category3"],["1002", "Category2"],["1001", "Category3"],["1001","Category4"]], columns=['Id','Cat']))
```

```
     Id        Cat
0  1001  Category1
1  1001  Category1
2  1001  Category2
3  1002  Category1
4  1002  Category3
5  1001  Category3
6  1002  Category2
7  1003  Category3
8  1001  Category4
```

and what I would like to obtain is a kind of co-occurrence like the following where for every ID that occurs in Category1, there is a count of the number of times that those IDs occur in each other Category;

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["nan","2","3","1"],["2","nan","2","1"],["3","2","nan","1"],["1","1","1","1"]],index = ['Category1','Category2','Category3'], columns=['Category1','Category2','Category3','Category4'])
```

```
          Category1 Category2 Category3 Category4
Category1         2         2         2         1
Category2         2         2         2         1
Category3         2         2         3         1
Category4         1         1         1         1
```

I was thinking about doing this using a `.groupby()` but I am not sure how to get every Category as in my example

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Cat'].value_counts()
"""
#Output:
Category1    4
Category3    3
Category2    2
Name: Cat, dtype: int64
"""
```

Would that solve your problem?

Comment: Sorry this isn't what I am looking for. I want to do this but split so that the totals show how many other categories IDs that fall into a category fall into.